# Bootstrap mobile menu does not open

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

On our website (www.ifi.training) the bootstrap mobile menu has stopped working after updating wordpress. When on mobile resoltuion, nothing happens when I press the menu icon. What is going wrong?

Comment: you didnt include `bootstrap.min.js` in your theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page, you should include bootstrap css and js files in order to get output as you desvribe here.
put these lines in your code between `<head>` and `</head>` and retry.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: glad to be a help. :)